# removing a line of javascript in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new at this...
I want to remove one line from the main.js file without editing the theme file (to keep it updateable).

How can I remove this line? with a custom javascript plugin maybe?

```
$('#footer-menu ul li').not(':last').append('/');
```

Comment: I don't use Wordpress, so I don't entirely understand the update issue, but couldn't you just comment the line out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot edit a javascript file without editing a javascript file.

If you are altering another theme, the best way to do this is to create a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). That way you can inherit the base styles of the theme that you want, but you won't risk overwriting your modifications when you update WP.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the slash:

```
var elements $('#footer-menu ul li').not(':last');
elements.each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.slice(0,-1));
});
```

The best thing to do, however, is to see if your theme is using the [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function. If it is, you can [wp_deregister_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) the javascript file in your function.php file and add your own version of the file.